# Load pickle file in gensim

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, gensim, word2vec

w2v = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load("w2v.pkl")

I am using this method to load pickle file through gensim but encountering an error.

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_load_specials'

Answer (score 1):

If you saved the model using `pickle`, you should be using some form of `unpickle` to re-load it. (Gensim has a utility method for unpickling a file containing a single pickled object at `[gensim.utils.unpickle][1]`.)

Gensim's per-instance `.save()` and per-class `.load()` methods are a custom save/load protocol that internally makes use of `pickle` but does other things (& perhaps spreads the model over multiple files) as well. You should only `Word2Vec.load(…)` a filename that was previously created by code like `w2v_model.save(…)`.